# What is the use of "dir" attribute in "del" tag?

Tags: html

I was looking into  tag in w3schools. I couldn't understand the purpose of dir attribute in it. Does anyone know?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_del.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`dir` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.2) determines the text direction, i.e. if text is written out from left to right, or from right to left.

The `dir` attribute is normally applied to the whole document, but you can override it in most block level elements.

Answer (score 3):

Writing direction. *Left to right* or *right to left*.

Comment: But how is direction concerned with del? It is just a strike through some text.

Comment: In no way. It is not about `del`, but its content.